# How to remove complex infinity

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, code-review, coding-style

I have an equation for the effective potential for a neutral particle (non-spinning), i.e.

```
VeffNonSPIN[r_, θ_] := (1 - 2/r)*(1 + LL^2/(r^2 Sin[θ]^2));
```

If I take double derivative with respect to θ, plug in a value, and simplify

```
Simplify[1/(r (r - 2))*D[D[VeffNonSPIN[r, θ], θ], θ] /. θ -> Pi/2]
```

I found the output

```
(2 LL^2)/r^4
```

This is OK.

Now, I have an equation for a spinning particle, which is a generalization of the above mentioned case, i.e.

```
VeffSpinP[r_, θ_] := ((((-2 + r) (-LL^2 (-3 + r) + r^3 - SS^2))/(r^3 - (-2 + r) SS^2) + (
    LL^2 (-2 + r) (r^3 (-3 + 2 r) + (-6 + r) SS^2) Sin[θ]^2)/(r^3 - (-2 + r) SS^2)^2 + (
    LL (r^3 (-5 + 2 r) - (-2 + r) SS^2) Sin[θ] Sqrt[((-2 + 
        r) ((LL - SS) (LL + SS) (-r^3 + (-2 + r) SS^2) + 
        LL^2 (r^3 + 2 SS^2) Sin[θ]^2))/(r^3 - (-2 + 
          r) SS^2)^2])/(r^4 - (-2 + r) r SS^2))/(
   Sqrt[-2 + r] Sqrt[r] Sqrt[
    1 + ((LL r^2 Sin[θ])/(r^3 - (-2 + r) SS^2) + 
       Sqrt[((-2 + r) ((LL - SS) (LL + SS) (-r^3 + (-2 + r) SS^2) + 
          LL^2 (r^3 + 2 SS^2) Sin[θ]^2))/(r^3 - (-2 + 
            r) SS^2)^2])^2]))^2;
```

For

```
AA = Simplify[1/(r (r - 2))*D[D[VeffSpinP[r, θ], θ], θ] /. θ -> Pi/2]
```

After simplification, in the limiting case (SS->0) my results should be for the same as for the neutral (non-spinning case) above mentioned case. But I'm not able to find the correct results; instead I'm getting infinity.

I have tried using

```
Limit[AA, ss -> 0]
```

I got the following output

```
DirectedInfinity[-((Sign[LL]^3 Sign[-3 + r] Sign[-2 + r]^2)/(Sign[r]^4 Sqrt[Sign[(-2 + r) (LL^2 + r^2)]/Sign[r]^5]))]/((-2 +  r)^2 r^2)
```

Here I want to remove DirectedInfinity and Sign. Can anyone help me please?

I also tried using

```
 SS=0; Simplify[AA]
```

but again found indeterminate form (infinity).

Can anyone please help me how can I remove this indeterminate form.

Comment: Have you double-checked your spinning model equations? There is nothing obviously wrong with your MMA code that I can see. As a note, the double derivative can be written as `D[VeffNonSPIN[r, θ], {θ, 2}]` which is more compact.

Comment: Yes, I have checked, I'm getting infinity answer for `Limit[AA, ss -> 0]`, instead answer should be `(2 LL^2)/r^4` as I mentioned in the question. Actually after calculating double derivatives I want to take limit for `SS->0`

Comment: For `Limit[A, SS -> 0]`, I'm getting this answer  `DirectedInfinity[-((Sign[LL]^3 Sign[-3 + r] Sign[-2 + r]^2)/(Sign[r]^4 Sqrt[Sign[(-2 + r) (LL^2 + r^2)]/Sign[r]^5]))]/((-2 +  r)^2 r^2)` , If I use the command `Simplify[Limit[A, SS -> 0], r > 3 && LL > 0]` then I have `- infinity`. but my answer should be `(2 LL^2)/r^4`

Comment: In the general case $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) \neq f(a)$ (see textbooks on calculus).

Comment: Yes in general case we don't have  `limx→a f(x) = f(a)`, Actually I was trying in both way, but not getting right answer.

Comment: @MMS: See https://context.reverso.net/перевод/английский-русский/in+the+general+case , it may be helpful.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the issue seems to be with the underlying math, rather than with the MMA code.

Comment: @MarcoB, I think you didn't understand my question correctly

Answer (score 1):

If you try

```
Normal[Series[
D[VeffSpinP[r, \[Theta]] /. SS -> 0, {\[Theta], 2}] /. \[Theta] -> 
Pi/2 - \[Epsilon], {\[Epsilon], 0, 0}]]
```

the result is an  expression without spin. If your spinning model is correct this should equal the non spinning result. Does it?

Edit:

Well I looked at the paper and the correct Potential is:

```
VeffSpinP[r_, \[Theta]_] := (((LL*Sin[\[Theta]])/
     r - (LL*r*Sin[\[Theta]])/(r^2 - (1 - 2/r)*SS^2) - 
    Sqrt[(LL^2*r^2*
         Sin[\[Theta]]^2)/(r^2 - (1 - 2/r)*
           SS^2)^2 - ((1 - 2/r)*(LL^2 - SS^2) + (2*LL^2*
            Sin[\[Theta]]^2)/r)/
                 (r^2 - (1 - 2/r)*SS^2)])*((LL*r*
       Sin[\[Theta]])/(r^2 - (1 - 2/r)*SS^2) + 
    Sqrt[(LL^2*r^2*
         Sin[\[Theta]]^2)/(r^2 - (1 - 2/r)*
           SS^2)^2 - ((1 - 2/r)*(LL^2 - SS^2) + (2*LL^2*
            Sin[\[Theta]]^2)/r)/
                 (r^2 - (1 - 2/r)*SS^2)]))/(Sqrt[1 - 2/r]*r*
        Sqrt[1 + ((LL*r*Sin[\[Theta]])/(r^2 - (1 - 2/r)*SS^2) + 
       Sqrt[(LL^2*r^2*
            Sin[\[Theta]]^2)/(r^2 - (1 - 2/r)*
              SS^2)^2 - ((1 - 2/r)*(LL^2 - SS^2) + (2*LL^2*
               Sin[\[Theta]]^2)/r)/(r^2 - (1 - 2/r)*
             SS^2)])^2]) + 
   Sqrt[1 - 2/r]*
Sqrt[1 + ((LL*r*Sin[\[Theta]])/(r^2 - (1 - 2/r)*SS^2) + 
     Sqrt[(LL^2*r^2*
          Sin[\[Theta]]^2)/(r^2 - (1 - 2/r)*
            SS^2)^2 - ((1 - 2/r)*(LL^2 - SS^2) + (2*LL^2*
             Sin[\[Theta]]^2)/r)/
                    (r^2 - (1 - 2/r)*SS^2)])^2];
```

Possibly you may further simplify.

Then you have:

```
FullSimplify[VeffSpinP[r, \[Theta]]^2 /. SS -> 0 /. \[Theta] -> Pi/2]
(*((-2 + r)*(LL^2 + r^2))/r^3*)
```

Edit 2:

I found now that your VeffSpinP is just the square of the one I gave.
Both coincide at \Theta=π/2 and SS=0 with the spinless case.
Why do you bother with the second derivative? If the two potentials (with and without spin) are the same at a point ( \Theta=π/2 and SS=0) it doesn't mean that their derivatives wrt.  \Theta are identical.

Comment: No I'm not getting this result. I'm sure, our spinning model is correct, I have taken this equation from already published articles. This equation is `2.31` from [https://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/9604020.pdf].

Comment: @ Andreas thanks for the help, actually I'm trying to calculate the frequency of the particle and in formula I have to use double derivative w.r.t `\theta`, and after calculations my results of spinning case should be reduced in spin-less case. I have done the same for radial co-ordinate (i.e., derivative w.r.t r), my results were reducing to spin-less case.

Comment: @MMS With `FullSimplify[
 PowerExpand[
  Normal[Series[
    Normal[Series[
      D[VeffSpinP[r, \[Theta]], {\[Theta], 2}] /. \[Theta] -> 
        Pi/2 - \[Epsilon], {\[Epsilon], 0, 0}]], {SS, 0, 0}]], {r, 
   SS}]]` you can see why there is a problem with the second derivative for SS->0

Comment: @ Andreas thanks for the help, I have tried this, this command is giving some output. But how can I see the problem for second derivative with the command you have mentioned in the comment. I'm sorry, I'm beginner, I'm not able to understand.

Comment: @MMS There appears a fraction with SS in the denominator which then will go to infinity with SS->0

Comment: yes, I have observed this thing